# how to auto show the category after value entry in php or html?

Tags: php, html

I have a input field suppose weight and another field where it will show the category based on the weight input without submitting. Like if i input 9 in the next field it will show 2. the categories are if weight <5 then 1, 5-10 then 2, 10-15 then 3 and so on. How to do it please help.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you be more specific and let us know what have u tried..

Comment: sorry no idea, i was doing it with submit button and getting the value through method GET

Comment: Could you at least post the whole form? :)

Comment: No way to do it in plain php-html. You want your page to interact with the user client-side, so you need javascript (or something alike)

Comment: @dirluca can you show some example ? which javascript or how to do it?

Comment: We can help you out with your code, not write it for you. Try go for some tutorial, I'd suggest [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzkAi2QMp7Y), then write your code and come back if it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this............

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chk(val)
{
    if(val<5)
        document.getElementById("scd").value = "1"
    if(val>=5 && val<=10)
        document.getElementById("scd").value = "2"
}
 </script>
     <input type="text" id="fst" onchange="chk(this.value)">
     <input type="text" id="scd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `jquery` -

```
<input type="text" id="sample">
```

In the script -

```
$('#sample').on('keyup change', function() {
     var val = $(this).val();
     if (val < 5) {
        $('yourselect').val(1);
     } else if () {} .... //so on
})
```

Comment: in that select field??

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 $options = array( '<5g', '5g-10g', '10g-20g' );

    $output = '';
    for( $i=0; $i<count($options); $i++ ) {
      $output .= '<option ' 
                 . ( $_GET['sel'] == $options[$i] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' 
                 . $options[$i] 
                 . '</option>';
    }
```